# Autolayout constraints with UITableViewCell to display two Views

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a UITableViewCell which has two UIViews, I want these two views to appear and resize as per screen size. Please see attached images to get an idea what I am trying to achieve, I have also attached constrains I have tried.

[image]

[image]

Please correct , whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is select both views and select the constraints

- "Equal Widths"
- "Equal Heights"
- "Align" -> "Vertical centers"

and then the margin between them and **margins to superview**